Align items between two vertically stacked divs - FlexBox
So I have a scenario like this. On Desktop mode, this is how the divs should be stacked. The div 2, 3 and 4 are stacked beside the div containing 1 and 5.


.container{
  display: flex;
}

.container div{
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sub-container{
  flex-direction: column;
}

.div1{
  background: red;
}

.div2{
  background: yellow;
}

.div3{
  background: green;
}

.div4{
  background: blue;
}

.div5{
  background: grey;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .container{
     flex-direction: column;
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub-container">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div5">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
  <div class="div4">4</div>
  
</div>



But on mobile screen-size (480px), the div 2, 3 and 4 should align vertically between div 1 and 5. Currently you see they are staked below the div 1 and 5. I want them in-between. Can I achieve this with flex-box? I don't wish to use grid layout.
I can't use order as div 1 and div 2 are part of the same group (.subcontainer).
So I have already seen the question with which this is marked as duplicate. However, that is not the same as this. Here div 1 and div 5  are two separate div and it's not just the same div with a bigger height.

So I have already seen the question with which this is marked as duplicate. However, that is not the same as this. Here div 1 and div 5  are two separate divs and it's not just the same div with a bigger height.

"Except, in this particular case, you need the order property to work (meaning all items must have the same parent), so a nested flex container is out of the question."

@Paulie_D I see. So you mean this can't be achieved through flexbox. Is it?

Technically, no. You have to "unwrap" the sub-container so that order can work. You can do this by using display: contents on that element - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KKOdQyR

@Paulie_D Oh yeah. Thank you. That's awesome.
